# Newbie. Troubleshooted with ServiceStack team

Tags: discussion

I'm a newbie. I'm wondering why my answer was deleted for
[Redis connection/buffer-size limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373769/redis-connection-buffer-size-limit-exceeded)

I have emailed the ServiceStack team this week because I had the same problem. I was able to reproduce the same problem on Window7 and worked this out to this solution of modifying the regedit. This looks to be an OS problem, not ServiceStack issue.

Again - I'm new. So let me know where I went wrong for the solution. Thanks

Comment: probably starting your answer with "I had the same problem" - someone in a hurry probably thought you didn't have an answer, just commiseration.

Comment: From your current answer it is not clear at all that it relates to redis and/or servicestack. If you edit that in it becomes a lot more clear how your answer addresses the problem of the OP.

Comment: I should have mentioned I noticed on Windows server 2008 r2 didn't have the same problem. So I thought it was OS related. I thought it was too much detail and didn't want to go off tangent.

Comment: I can still edit it even though it is deleted? Or do I need someone to undelete it?

Comment: You should be able to edit it while it's deleted as long as you weren't the one deleting it.

Answer (score 9):

You posted the exact same answer to two different questions:

- [Redis connection/buffer-size limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373769/redis-connection-buffer-size-limit-exceeded)
- [Redis unable to connect in busy load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213870/redis-unable-to-connect-in-busy-load)

This raises a red flag: did you *really* have the same problem (as you stated)? If so, *which* problem? Both? Are they the same problem with different symptoms? Different problems with the same solution? You don't say... As a result, it's not at all clear that *either* answer actually applies to the question under which it is posted.

I've undeleted [*one*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373769/redis-connection-buffer-size-limit-exceeded/21608690#21608690) of your answers, but you should consider editing both of them to reflect the specific circumstances you're addressing, and note how your solution applies (if it *does* apply to both).

Comment: Okay I edited both. I have one post reference the other. Thanks for the feedback.